# Returning a 0 on my matrix hourglass calculating function

Tags: c++

I'm having issues with this set of codes and I have no idea why, so the purpose of this code is to get a value of an hourglass figure in a matrix. For example.

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 2 4 4 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 1 2 4 0
```

And this is meant to take in the highest amount from all the possible hour glass, so for those who don't get the code, it's meant to take for example,

```
1 1 1
  1 
1 1 1
```

That's the hourglass shape, it's supposed to find the max of all of them and output it, in this case, the maximum would be 19. But for some reason, when the values in the matrix is negative, my cout always returns a 0 instead of a negative number, and I don't understand why. It'll be great if someone could enlighten me. Thank you.

```
0 -4 -6 0 -7 -6
-1 -2 -6 -8 -3 -1
-8 -4 -2 -8 -8 -6
-3 -1 -2 -5 -7 -4
-3 -5 -3 -6 -6 -6
-3 -6 0 -8 -6 -7
```

Example of negative input.

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> arr(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        arr[i].resize(6);

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }

        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    int maximumoutput = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for(int r = 0; r < 4; r++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
            for(int c = i; c < i+3; c++){
                temp += arr[r][c];
                temp += arr[r+2][c];
            }
            temp += arr[r+1][i+1];
            maximumoutput = temp > maximumoutput ? temp : maximumoutput;
            temp = 0;
        }
    }

    cout << maximumoutput;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you initialized the maximumoutput with 0. So you will never get any value below 0 because of this check:

```
maximumoutput = temp > maximumoutput ? temp : maximumoutput;
```

To fix, you need to initialize maximumoutput with minimum possible value

```
maximumoutput = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

Answer (score 0):

that because you initialized max by 0 .. and the the result of code should be -19  and that is less than 0 which was the first value for max

you need to add a condition that checks if you are in the first of the matrix like this

```
    int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> arr(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        arr[i].resize(6);

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }

        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    int maximumoutput = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for(int r = 0; r < 4; r++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
            for(int c = i; c < i+3; c++){
                temp += arr[r][c];
                temp += arr[r+2][c];
            }
            temp += arr[r+1][i+1];
             // here edition 
            if(r == 0 && i==0){
                maximumoutput = temp;
            }
            maximumoutput = temp > maximumoutput ? temp : maximumoutput;
            temp = 0;
        }
    }

    cout << maximumoutput;

    return 0;
}
```